# When i debug on data sent by angularjs I find array empty in IsAuthorized on Cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cakephp

Please I can't find out where the problem is. I can't get my data sent in CakePHP. I always get an empty array or `null`.

**Controller.js**

```js
$scope.valider=function()
     {
    
      var data={'Demande':{'id':window.localStorage.getItem("demande_val_id")},
            'GroupeDemande':{
  "remarque_responsable":window.localStorage.getItem("demande_val_responsable")
          }}
          
          console.log("data-send",data)
          $http.post("http://localhost/demandes/valider.json",data).then(function(success){
            console.log("data",success.data)

             var alertPopup=$ionicPopup.alert({
                  title: ' bon',
        template: 'le demande est valider.'
             })
             $state.go("app.TDBcong")
          },function(erreur){

          })
        }
```

**Appcontroller.php**

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    debug($this->request->data);
    die("i'm in isAuth");
}
```

Comment: Your JavaScript example is syntactically invalid. When posting code, please make sure it's valid, otherwise people may get distracted from the actual problem that you're experiencing.

Comment: thanks i edited it